# css3 transform scale stick to bottom

Tags: css, frontend, transform, scale

Is it possible to use the transform: scale(x) property while keeping the element stuck to the bottom of the page? (by default if scales relative to the center of the element as shown below)

[image: default scale behavior]
<sub>(source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/transform_scale.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use the [`transform-origin`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3styleproperties/p/transform-origin.htm) property :

```
element{
    -webkit-transform : scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform : scale(0.5);
    -o-transform : scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform : scale(0.5);
    transform : scale(0.5);

    -webkit-transform-origin : 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin : 50% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin : 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin : 50% 100%;
    transform-origin : 50% 100%;
}
```

Here's [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa9eS/1/) that shows the `transform-origin` in action.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. The link is broken though (remove the trailing /)

Answer (score 0):

the question is whether you can choose what the axis is for an object. i dont know the answer to this and i'm guessing its probably not.

if you really cant set the "the axis" you'll have to transform the box while moving it simultaneously.